# how to get loss of each output in multi output regression?

Tags: python, regression

In order to analyze data, I need loss for each of output dimensions, instead I get only one loss which i suspect is a mean of the losses for all output dimensions.

Any help to understand what is the loss I get and how to get separate loss for each output:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
from scipy import stats
from keras import models 
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from keras import optimizers
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

siz=100000
inp0=np.random.randint(100, 1000000 , size=(siz,3))
rand0=np.random.randint(-100, 100 , size=(siz,2))
a1=0.2;a2=0.8;a3=2.5;a4=2.6;a5=1.2;a6=0.3
oup1=np.dot(inp0[:,0],a1)+np.dot(inp0[:,1],a2)+np.dot(inp0[:,2],a3)\
+rand0[:,0]
oup2=np.dot(inp0[:,0],a4)+np.dot(inp0[:,1],a5)+np.dot(inp0[:,2],a6)\
 +rand0[:,1]
 oup_tot=np.concatenate((oup1.reshape(siz,1), oup2.reshape(siz,1)),\
                   axis=1)
normzer_inp = MinMaxScaler()
 inp_norm = normzer_inp.fit_transform(inp0)
 normzer_oup = MinMaxScaler()
 oup_norm = normzer_oup.fit_transform(oup_tot)
 X=inp_norm
Y=oup_norm
kfold = KFold(n_splits=2, random_state=None, shuffle=False)
opti_SGD = SGD(lr=0.01, momentum=0.9)
model1 = Sequential()
for train, test in kfold.split(X, Y):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(64, input_dim=X.shape[1], activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(Y.shape[1], activation='linear'))
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=opti_SGD)

    history = model.fit(X[train], Y[train], \
            validation_data=(X[test], Y[test]), \
            epochs=100,batch_size=2048, verbose=2)
```

I get:

```
Epoch 1/100
  - 0s - loss: 0.0864 - val_loss: 0.0248

Epoch 2/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.0218 - val_loss: 0.0160

Epoch 3/100
  - 0s - loss: 0.0125 - val_loss: 0.0091
```

I would like to know what is the loss i got now and how to get losses for each output dimension.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a list of functions to the `metrics` argument in the compile function. See here: https://keras.io/metrics/#custom-metrics

```
import keras.backend as K

...

def loss_first_dim(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(K.square(y_pred[:, 0] - y_true[:, 0]))

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=[loss_first_dim])

...
```